# Putting links in contact in UIWebView and display on different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a view controller in which I have created a simple contact app using Apple's addressbook, I have created another view controller which has a web view that create and displays all contacts and phonenumber when a user click on generate button. Now what I need is that, on generate the contacts should be hyperlinks, and when I click on any contact it should display the details of contact which I have done it in my 1st view controller. I know I have to use the delete of webview but not sure how to implement it, so far this is all I have written.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    ViewController *latestView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:latestView animated:YES]; 
    return YES;
}
```

This is the function that generates and displays contacts in webview, in this I want to know how to add hyperlink along with the contact details

```
- (IBAction)createFileAction:(id)sender {



    NSString *tweet, *phoneNumbers=@"", *temp, *allContacts=@"";
    addressBooks =ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBooks);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++)
    {
        person12 = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
         tweet=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person12, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        //Appending Last Name
        if(CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person12,kABPersonLastNameProperty))!=NULL)
        {
            tweet=[tweet stringByAppendingString:@" "];
            tweet=[tweet stringByAppendingString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person12, kABPersonLastNameProperty)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
        }


        tweet=[@"<h5>" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tweet]];
        if(CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person12,kABPersonFirstNameProperty))!=NULL)
        {


            ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person12, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multi)!=0)
            {
            //For fetching multiple Phone Numbers
            for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++) 
                {
            temp = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
                phoneNumbers=[phoneNumbers stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",temp]];
                }



            //For Trimming characters in contacts (),-," "

            NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()-\" \""];
            phoneNumbers = [[phoneNumbers componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: trim] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
            phoneNumbers=[phoneNumbers substringToIndex:[phoneNumbers length]- 1];
            if([phoneNumbers rangeOfString:@"/"].location!=NSNotFound)
            {
                phoneNumbers = [phoneNumbers stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@" / "];
            }
            }
            else
            {
                phoneNumbers=[phoneNumbers stringByAppendingString:@"No Numbers"];

            }

            tweet=[tweet stringByAppendingString:@" ---> "];
            tweet=[tweet stringByAppendingString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneNumbers] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
            phoneNumbers=@"";

            NSLog(@"%@",tweet); 

        allContacts = [allContacts stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@</h5>",tweet];
        }

    }
    CFBridgingRelease(people);


        // To create file
        [self.fileMgr createFileAtPath:file contents:nil attributes:nil];

        [allContacts writeToFile:self.file atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];


        //Test if file exists now that we have tried creating it
        if([self.fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:self.file])
        {

            NSString *content = @"Contact list generated click on view to show the list";
            [webview loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
        }
        else 
        {

            NSString *content = @"Contact list is not created yet, click on create to generate the contact list";
            [webview loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
        }



}
```

Can you suggest the modifications to these two codes which will help me achieve the results??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have HTML links that open and instance of ViewController. Basically you can create any type of link `<a href="myapp://{some_id_of_the_person}">click here</a>`, assuming you want to pass the person's id to your ViewController.

Then in `[UIWebView webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` check if `request.URL.scheme` matches your scheme (`myapp://`) in the example:

- If yes, parse the URL for the person's id and open your viewController for that person (and `return NO` to the method).
- If not just `return YES` (assuming there might be some other standard links in the view that should be opened normally).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have managed to add hyperlinks in my contact, but when I click on the hyperlink the function [UIWebView webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] doesnt get called (I checked with help of breakpoint). On NSLog this is a sample how my contact value looks like <h5><a href="myapp://">Firstname LastName ---> 9876543210</a></h5>. Do I have to add any thing else in the href to be able to trigger the function [UIWebView webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]

Comment: I figured it out, I had to set my delegate. Thanks for your help.